# Cannot print out the array when reading it from an existing file

Tags: arrays, perl, file-io

I have a data file, with each line holding one number. I am trying to read this file into an array. Here is the script I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$file1 = '/home/usr1/test.list';
open(FILEC, $file1);
my @cArray = FILEC;
close FILEC;
print @cArray;
```

But after executing this file, nothing was printed out? I have checked the input, test.list, which is at the correct location. What may be the reason?

Comment: Yet another case where `use strict` and `use warnings` would have helped track down the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `<>`(line) operator:

```
my @cArray = <FILEC>;
```

ought to help.

Answer (score 1):

FatalError is correct, you need a readline operator. You can read more about `<>` in [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) and more about the `readline` function in [`perldoc -f readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html).

Once you have that knowledge, you can see why the following could also work (though perhaps not recommended for readability). Also I will use [`Data::Dumper`](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper) to print a better representation of `@cArray`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

@ARGV = qw( /home/usr1/test.list ); 
# or remove previous line and call script as
# script.pl /home/usr1/test.list

my @cArray = <>;

print Dumper \@cArray;
```

Some further notes: a more modern version of your would:

- use the three argument form of [`open`](http://p3rl.org/open)
- check that open succeeds
- use a lexical rather than bareword handle
- `use strict` as well as `use warnings` (rather than `-w`)

giving

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = '/home/usr1/test.list';
open(my $handle, '<', $file1)
  or die "Could not open $file1: $!";
my @cArray = <$handle>;

print @cArray;
```